# Binding the select option list

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am currently unsure on how should I be doing this. When the method = RequestMethod.POST, how should I bind the select picker to my object.

This is part of my form

```
<form th:action="@{/incidentDetail/update}" method="post" id="incidentDetailForm">

<div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="location">Name</label> <input class="form-control"
                    type="text" name="ioName" id="ioName" th:value="${incident.ioName}" />
    </div>

       <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="location" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Preparation
                    By</label><span class="bg-danger pull-right"></span>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-reorder fa"
                            aria-hidden="true"></i></span> <select class="form-control selectpicker"
                            th:object="${incident}" th:field="*{incidentPreparationBy}"
                            id="incidentPreparationBy" name="incidentPreparationBy"
                            roleId="incidentPreparationBy">
                            <option th:each="user: ${userList}" th:value="${incident.incidentPreparationBy}"
                                th:text="${user.name}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerIncidentPost(@ModelAttribute("incident") Incident incident, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws Exception {

        incidentService.save(incident);

        return "redirect:/incidentDetail?id=" + incident.getId();
    }
```

Part of Incident Entity

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id_preparation_by")
    private User incidentPreparationBy;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acces the select by adding:

`@RequestParam("incidentPreparationBy") String option` as a method argument

to your controller method.
This way the string "option" will contain the selected value.

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerIncidentPost(@ModelAttribute("incident") Incident incident, 
    @RequestParam("incidentPreparationBy") String option, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    String incidentPrepartionBy = option; //incidentPrepartionBy will give you the selected value now.
    incidentService.save(incident);

    return "redirect:/incidentDetail?id=" + incident.getId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. This method works. I am just wondering, is there any other methods without using the @RequestParam and just through the @ModelAttribute. The other input text field are updated just fine for example ```<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="location">Report No*</label> <input class="form-control"
     type="text" name="incidentReportNo" id="incidentReportNo"
     th:value="${incident.incidentReportNo}" />
   </div>```

Comment: I'd probably need more code to give you a correct answer, but I don't think it's possible here. Because the type of incidentPreparationBy in the select is a String and in the Entity class it's of type User. I think this is the reason why it's not working.

Comment: @user2833581 Feel free to upvote/accept if it helped you by the way. Helps me earn more reputation to unlock more features! :)